Calculating FID score for (x, 3) size data frame
I have a dataset consists of rows of synthetic acceleration data according to x, y, z axis basically like the shape of (N, 3). I want to calculate the FID score between this synthetic dataset and the original one which is also the same shape. I know that covariance and mean of the datasets must be calculated to find the fid scores and the order of the data doesn't make a difference. But I'm not sure about how to put that together. I thought datasets can be flattened onto (M, 1) shaped dataframes but that doesn't sound like the best idea. I'd like some advices, thank you!
FID = |μ1 − μ2|2 + Tr(Σ1 + Σ2 − 2(Σ1Σ2)1/2)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
